# Android - can a final static reference to a Class object cause memory leak?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, static

In my app I have few tabs and the user can switch between different Fragments in the same tab (I'm employing nested fragments for this).

In order to specify which Fragment is the default ("the first") for each tab, I defined the following static map:

```
/**
This map is used in order to map tab's tags into default fragments for these tabs
 */
public static final Map<String, Class> DEFAULT_TAB_FRAGMENT_MAP;
static {
    Map<String, Class> map = new HashMap<String, Class>();
    map.put(HOME_TAB_TAG, HomeFragment.class);
    map.put(HISTORY_LIST_TAB_TAG, HistoryFragment.class);
    map.put(HISTORY_CLOCK_TAB_TAG, HistoryClockFragment.class);
    map.put(SETTINGS_TAB_TAG, SettingsFragment.class);
    map.put(EXTRAS_TAB_TAG, ExtrasFragment.class);
    DEFAULT_TAB_FRAGMENT_MAP = Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
}
```

The above map allows me to query the Class of the default fragment for a particular tab (which is defined by a String tag).

At some point I realized that my app got memory leaks - garbage collector works like a maniac even when my app is in background. Can it be that static references to Class variables cause memory leaks?

Comment: I don't think so. Because this refrence will not re-create so there will be only one instance. By the way you can use preferences instead-of using constant-map.

Comment: @PankajKumar, thx for your comment. Using preferences feels wrong - this information is never changing and I don't see any reason to allocate persistent storage space for it... Am I missing your point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I got 2 years of experience in Android development (and Java in general), I think that I can answer my own newbie question: no, static reference to class object does not cause memory leaks.